# IE 7, Javascript transparent div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Well i have a transparent div or the background is set to transparent :)
css:

```
#lowerLayer
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: Transparent;
    cursor: help;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The div is placed right under the  tag.. and under there i have a [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) layout.

jquery(this is run in $(document).ready):

```
$("#lowerLayer").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0, function() {
        $(this).hide(0);
    });
});
```

My layout works perfect in Opera 10 and i guess it works in Opera 9 to... but IE 7 bugs layers that have lower z-index are acting as they are above the transparent div...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to place the transparent div (#lowerLayer) last in the html (just before the closing `</body>`.

It's a known issue with some browsers (IE for example)

EDIT: as mentioned in my comment, the [blockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) handles everything you may ever need if you want to mask your page with an overlay.

Comment: well it was worth a try but it did not help :( +1

Comment: When the transparent div has the highest z-index, and it is last in the HTML, it will always be above anything else on the page (with the exception of dropdown lists on IE, which is a bug). A better option would be to use the blockUI plugin (I've added the link in my answer)

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem with IE7 and found easier solution.
Instead making your div transparent using css use javascript to set it's opacity.

Following your example:

css style

`#lowerLayer {

      position: fixed;

      top: 0px;

      left: 0px;

      width: 100%;

      height: 100%;

      background-color: #000;

      cursor: help;

      z-index: 1;

}`

javascript code (e.g. after DOM tree is loaded)

`document.getElementById("lowerLayer").style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";`

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Seems that if a div is empty and transparent (no background colour) IE doesn't capture clicks on it. Giving it a background colour and setting opacity to 0 works around this.